# ROS Answers SE migration: Laser 3D map

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, 3dmapping, vlp-16

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Hi, I am going to use a Velodyne
  VLP-16 to create a 3D map. It is
  going to go on a  moving "robot/car"
  so it will likely have the wheel
  odometry. The algorithm does not need
  to run in real time.
- Currently I get to publish the
  PointCloud2 from the device. I need
  to create a 3D map by combining these
  pointclouds. I use ROS Indigo, could
  ypu give me some advice about what
  package could I use?  loam seemed
  pretty good but it has been removed
  from public access, I got to use a
  old version but it sometimes loses
  the odometry.
- I would like to know the process of
  what I have to do to create a 3D map
  from different pointclouds; and what
  packages should I use. I have seen
  things like octomap, but I am not
  sure if that is what I need.

Thanks a lot!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233171/laser-3d-map/) by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-04-29**:
Octomap seems popular and is worth trying. You may also want to sub-sample to an appropriately-sized voxelgrid or similar filter.

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-05-03**:
ok, would I have just to suscribe octomap to the velodyne pointCloud2 topic to do make de 3D map? or would I also have to provide a tf, odom, or something like that?

**Comment by [chukcha2](https://answers.ros.org/users/25963/chukcha2/) on 2016-06-08**:
I asked a similar question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/octomap/xz2A9U6emfA/dH6Ji6dWAQAJ) and the response was that you'll still need to provide transforms to octomap for it to combine (register) the point clouds to create a 3D map.

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-06-13**:
and what was your solution to provide the location? using an IMU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have any personal experience with octomap, but looking at the docs there appear to be several options:

- [a standalone library](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap) with no ROS dependencies
- [a ROS wrapper package](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_ros) with various message conversion functions

You probably do want to provide appropriate transforms to the `odom` coordinate frame.

Perhaps someone more knowledgeable will provide additional suggestions.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1